# Android Honeycomb, get instance of Fragments?

Tags: android, instance, android-fragments, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a PreferenceActivity that loads two Fragments via the xml file for the headers.

I don't seem to be able to set a tag or an ID. or a tag for the fragments in the header xml (that is loaded using loadHeaderFromResource();

Since I don't instantiate it myself I have no ID. or reference to get hold of it.

What do I do?

Comment: What do you need to do with the Fragment? Perhaps you can accomplish this use case using some other means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think preference fragments loaded via XML are given a tag, and AFAIK they don't have a known ID, so the only way to do this *may* be to (1) maintain a separate `List<WeakReference<Fragment>>` in your `PreferenceActivity` and add to that list in the Activity's `onAttachFragment` and (2) later on, look in that list when you need to find a particular fragment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in the end I did a complete re-write of my UI implementation so that my fragments are loaded in code by myself so i have a handle on them, this way i have complete control which made life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to do that?

Just did so using the line:

```
Fragment shown = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frgHome);
```

Comment: There is no ID for the xml loaded fragments which is why i couldn't use this method, in the end I managed the fragments myself.