# How to show different Activities in Fragment implementation?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget, android-manifest

It is my first time using android fragment. I am following [this tutorial](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) to implement a fragment.

Everything is fine with this tutorial, I successfully get the result like below:

[image]

In the tutorial, the **DetailsFragment** simply shows a `TextView` containing the text of the currently selected item. That's the right part shows just some texts.

My question is how to show different **activities** on the right side instead of text views.

What I mean is illustrated in the following image, for example, the area of "**1**" in the image is an activity. How to show different activities when a list item on the left hand side has selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show an activity, you show a fragment. Implement the Fragment class instead of the Activity class. Then you build your View just as you would in an Activity. Remember that for instances when you need access to an activity the Fragment class has the convenient getActivity() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FragmentManager.beginTransaction()` to start `FragmentTransaction`. With that operation you can hide and show new Fragments. It is also managed with the android history stack.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#beginTransaction()
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

And here is some code: [Android Honeycomb: How to change Fragments in a FrameLayout, without re-creating them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185272/android-honeycomb-how-to-change-fragments-in-a-framelayout-without-re-creating)