# is there a way to display an activity within a fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I am using a navigation drawer in my Map application, I managed to display the map on the main page. The problem am having is that I cannot connect the map fragment (in the layout "xml") to the MapsActivity (java file).

I tried to use `MapsActivity extends Fragment` instead of `MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity` but of course this does not work.

the main xml layout:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


 <!-- *****The problem I am having is in the following fragment could not link it to the MapsActivity-->
 <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>


</FrameLayout>


<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.famfelimban.mydiet.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

However, I have a separate xml layout for the map which is working fine
activity_maps.xml which is working fine with the MapsActivity

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

MapsActivity

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

    }

    private void setUpMap() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `Activity`s are holders for `Fragment`s, and `Fragment`s can't hold Activities.

This question might be of interest: [How to show different Activities in Fragment implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693649/how-to-show-different-activities-in-fragment-implementation)

Comment: yes I know, but is there any other way to do it ?
being browsing for 2 days and found nothing

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here is port your `Activity` code into a `Fragment`. It's not hard, a fragment has an almost identical lifecycle. The only difference is instead of grabbing and modifying the `View`s in `onCreate` you need to do it in `onCreateView` and you need to implement a `static newInstance()` method.

Leave the `FrameLayout` in the xml empty. It's only there for the `FragmentManager` to inflate the fragment into. Two changes to code

in the `Activity`

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Fragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance(/*args*/);
    getFragmentManager()  //you may need getSupportFragmentMananger()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, mapFragment)
            .commit()
    //this inflates the Fragment into the FrameLayout
}
```

and make a `Fragment` that functions like your `Activity` version

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    public MapFragment() {/*should be empty*/}
    ...
    public static MapFragment newInstance(/*args*/) {
        Fragment fragment = new MapFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //put whatever information you need for your activity to run here
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    ...
    @Overide
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //this basically takes the place of onCreate in the Activity version
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, parent);

        View yourView = root.findViewById(R.id.your_view);
        ...
        return root;
    }
    ...
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so do you mean that I only have the onStart() in my Activity and then implement all the methods from the Activity into the fragment?

Comment: `onCreate()` is still  there. `setContentView()` still  needs to be called and you could do the `Fragment` transaction in `onCreate()`, but the `Activity`'s main job is to start the `Fragment` which does all the heavy lifting.