# how to hide/show fragment defined in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I have been trying to hide/show fragment and add another fragment.
This is xml

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <fragment
        class="com.tugce.MitsActionBar.KartvizitFragment"
        android:id="@+id/frag_kartvizit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
        </FrameLayout>
```

After calling something else and calling this fragment again, its mAdded property is false so when i tried to access getView() it is null.

I tried every edit in this post: [Android Honeycomb: How to change Fragments in a FrameLayout, without re-creating them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185272/android-honeycomb-how-to-change-fragments-in-a-framelayout-without-re-creating)
But still cannot manage to make it work.

Comment: It seems like fragment is added to view but not seen, and it is not hidden

Answer (score 1):

You can add `android:visibility` flag to the parent layout (in this case framelayout) of the fragment inside xml and use that in your java code.