# Nested Fragments using support library v4 revision 11

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library, android-nested-fragment

The last revision of the support library from this morning ([Android Support Package v4 revision 11](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Notes)) is supposed to support nested fragments.

In my project I have a fragment that contains a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and this ViewPager contains several fragments.

I'm calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager` to use the [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html) of the support library.

The problem is I'm still experiencing crashes like :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:495)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onRestoreInstanceState(ViewPager.java:1221)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:11910)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2584)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2590)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11888)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:417)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:933)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong ? Or the support doesn't support nested fragments for real ?

My transactions are as simple as this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content, new MyFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: What the type of element is R.id.content?

Comment: Have you read this article ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185272/android-honeycomb-how-to-change-fragments-in-a-framelayout-without-re-creating

Comment: I just did, but I don't think this is related. My problem is about nesting the fragments, replacing them is working ok. :)

Comment: Check out the answer I have to this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379194/how-to-add-a-fragment-inside-a-viewpager-using-nested-fragment-android-4-2/13391359#13391359 I also provide a link to a repo where I have a simple implementation

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`. this should help

Comment: What? `getChildFragmentManager()` can only be used inside fragments and `getSupportFragmentManager()` can only be used inside FragmentActivity? How would this ever work?