# Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, forceclose

I have a MainDrawer to Fragment activity which has a layout for a nav drawer my and my main content where I can load new fragments into. One fragment I load in is calle StatisticsTab Fragment. This Fragment holds a tabhost which each tab is its own fragment of listview items. Once I click on a ListView item, which loads another new fragment and am no longer in the tabHost and I try to go back using the navigationdrawer to my StatisticsTab fragment I get this error:

```
03-03 10:32:06.884  24185-24185/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1439)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:283)
            at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:12307)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2457)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2464)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3567)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3399)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3344)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3320)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I do not click on any of my tabs though on the StatisticsTab fragment and navigate to another fragment via the navdrawer and then back to the StatisticsTab then it will not FC on. ALso none of the other fragments in the NavDrawer force close when I go back to them, just the one with the tabs.

MainDrawer2:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static final String EXTRA_NAV_ITEM    = "extraNavItem";
    private static final String STATE_CURRENT_NAV = "stateCurrentNav";

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

    private NavDrawerListAdapter mDrawerAdapter;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    private MainNavItem mCurrentNavItem;


    public static Intent createLaunchFragmentIntent(Context context, MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        return new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class)
                .putExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM, navItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList   = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        enableHomeButtonIfRequired();

        mDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                displayNavFragment((MainNavItem)parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
        {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
            {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if(getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM)){
            MainNavItem navItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_NAV_ITEM,
                    MainNavItem.STATISTICS.ordinal())];
            displayNavFragment(navItem);
        }
        else if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mCurrentNavItem = MainNavItem.values()
                    [savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV)];
            setCurrentNavItem(mCurrentNavItem);
        }
        else{
            displayNavFragment(MainNavItem.STATISTICS);
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private void enableHomeButtonIfRequired()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title)
    {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_CURRENT_NAV, mCurrentNavItem.ordinal());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    */



    private void displayNavFragment(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        if(navItem == mCurrentNavItem){
            return;
        }
        Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,
                navItem.getFragClass().getName());
        if(fragment != null){

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment)
                    .commit();
            setCurrentNavItem(navItem);
        }
    }

    private void setCurrentNavItem(MainNavItem navItem)
    {
        int position = navItem.ordinal();
        // If navItem is in DrawerAdapter
        if(position >= 0 && position < mDrawerAdapter.getCount()){
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        else{
            // navItem not in DrawerAdapter, de-select current item
            if(mCurrentNavItem != null){
                mDrawerList.setItemChecked(mCurrentNavItem.ordinal(), false);
            }
        }
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setTitle(navItem.getTitleResId());
        mCurrentNavItem = navItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                else {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new Search();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

StatisticsTab:

```
public class StatisticsTab extends Fragment  {


    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    //Mandatory Constructor
    public StatisticsTab() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs,container, false);


        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Basic").setIndicator("Basic"),
                StatisticsPage.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Brewery").setIndicator("Brewery"),
                BreweryStatistics.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Style").setIndicator("Style"),
                StyleStatistics.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Taste").setIndicator("Taste"),
                TasteStatisticsPage.class, null);



        return rootView;
    }




}
```

One of my Fragments for a tab in the tabhost which has a listview:

```
public class BreweryStatistics extends Fragment implements GetBreweryStatisticsJSON.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.brewery_statistics_layout, container, false);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

        String url = "myURL";


        //async task to get beer taste tag percents
        GetBreweryStatisticsJSON task = new GetBreweryStatisticsJSON(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(url);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return v;

    }


    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String bID){

        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment_one = new BreweryPage2();
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("breweryIDSent", bID);
        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }


}
```

My Async task for the above fragment to load the listview:

```
public class GetBreweryStatisticsJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;


    public GetBreweryStatisticsJSON(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    //***************************code for on click
    OnArticleSelectedListener listener;
    public interface OnArticleSelectedListener{
        public void onArticleSelected(String myString);


    }
    public void setOnArticleSelectedListener(OnArticleSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;


    }
    //*****************************end code for onClick

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Analyzing breweries");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.yourBreweryStatistics);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<BreweryInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<BreweryInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String brewery = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("brewery");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String breweryID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                int count = i + 1;

                brewery = count + ". " + brewery;

                Log.d("brewery stats", brewery);

                //create object
                BreweryInfo tempTaste = new BreweryInfo(brewery, breweryID, rate);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                BreweryInfoAdapter adapter1 = new BreweryInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        BreweryInfo o=(BreweryInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String bID = o.breweryID;

                        Log.d("breweryID" , bID);

                        //todo: add brewery page link
                        //********************* add listener
                        listener.onArticleSelected(bID);


                    }
                });

            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }



}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewPager: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338823/viewpager-recursive-entry-to-executependingtransactions)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You are attempting to use fragments nested within other fragments, by way of your FragmentTabHost.

In your StatisticsTab fragment, change this:

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

to this:

```
mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);
```

Then, make sure to use the parent FragmentManager to commit the main fragment change, by changing `getFragmentManager()` to `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` inside `BreweryStatistics.onArticleSelected()`.

See:
[ViewPager: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338823/viewpager-recursive-entry-to-executependingtransactions)
[Nested Fragments using support library v4 revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377157/nested-fragments-using-support-library-v4-revision-11)

Comment: where would i change to getSupportFragmentManager() vs getChildFragmentManager()?

Comment: Apologies, misread your Activity code, you are using getSupportFragmentManager() correctly in your drawer activity.  See my updated answer for clarification.

Comment: awesome, but that is actually what I had originally and I get an odd ID error when I try and make a selection from my ListView thats in the tab. I will change it back real quick and show you the error.

Comment: this si the error I get when in my brewery statistics tab and try and selecet an item from the listview: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/14131f62e19f8e0b04cc

Comment: In BreweryStatistics.onArticleSelected(), the call to getFragmentManager() returns the child FragmentManager supplied initially by the FragmentTabHost setup.  This fragment manager is independent of the main fragment manager from the Activity, and therefore will not have any references to the main fragment manager's views.  You need to replace getFragmentManager() with getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() and all should be well.

Comment: You are then man!! Thank you soo much, been trying to solve this one forever!

Comment: @Bryan Dunlap ur god to me man.. getChildFragmentManager holy chick