# Calling getSupportFragmentManager() after getChildFragmentManager() causes IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, android-nested-fragment

I am using FrameLayout to show fragments

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:background="@android:color/white" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

and to open fragment i am using this

```
ft.add(R.id.fragment_content, frag);
ft.commit();
fm.beginTransaction();
```

One fragment contains map so i am using these lines in layout file

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/trafic_Alarm_main_mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.Utilities.MySupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

and this is my Java code

```
try{
mMap=(MySupportMapFragment)TabsActivity.fm.findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();
}catch (Exception e){
mMap=((MySupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();
}
```

Now, if getChildFragmentManager() gets called and i switch to another fragment that uses getSupportFragmentManager to begin transaction causes crash . Provding logs

```
01-16 18:36:15.690    7294-7294/com.TrafikAlarm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.TrafikAlarm, PID: 7294
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1461)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I am using android studio and compiling these libraries ,

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

When i was using eclipse i did not need to use getChildFragmentManager and everything was working fine .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats the context of that Java code? Where is it located. In the parent Fragment I assume?

Comment: May be You are attempting to use fragments nested within other fragments. refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150950/recursive-entry-to-executependingtransactions

Comment: Andy , context is fragment activity class.

Comment: Why are you calling `fm.beginTransaction();` a second time?

Comment: Matish , it gets one call only

Comment: You're calling it twice in the code you posted

Comment: What exception are you catching? When is this code to get the map executed? You know it isn't ready immediately?

Comment: @darnmason i am making transaction in fragment activity class and getting MySupportMapFragment in inner fragment class

Comment: Sorry , i am not calling begin transaction twice in code , i have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the bug . I was using FragmentActivity manager to return map object to remove map fragment that was causing problem and logs were not . So , i changed

```
TabsActivity.fm.beginTransaction().remove((MySupportMapFragment) TabsActivity.fm.findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).commit();
```

to

```
TabsActivity.fm.beginTransaction().remove((MySupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a fragment. Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)
2. [FILL_PARENT (renamed MATCH_PARENT in API Level 8 and higher).](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: I tried using this , i am getting same error 
mMap=((MySupportMapFragment)getParentFragment().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getFragmentManager()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1):

Since your context is a fragment, have you tried calling super on your child fragment manager before you use it?

super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());

Comment: Where should i call it ?

Comment: first line in the method where this resides:

`try{
mMap=(MySupportMapFragment)TabsActivity.fm.findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();
}catch (Exception e){
mMap=((MySupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();
}`

Comment: I am not using it in any overrided method. The parent overrided method is onCreateView and that does not support super(fragment.getChildFragmentManager());

Answer (score 1):

Hi it appears that you are having a recursive problem  `Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions` since you are reapeting the call more than once, and in an Exception Handling which by practice is wrong to catch an Exeption error and try to "do something()"

```
try{

mMap=(MySupportMapFragment)TabsActivity.fm.findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();

}catch (Exception e){

mMap=((MySupportMapFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.trafic_Alarm_main_mapView)).getMap();

}
```

Remove the **unnecessary** call on the `catch` area, If a new error appear make sure to read the log cat, and do the adding/removing of fragment in the correct `@override` such as `@onCreate` of your activity working with the `fragment`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Layout fragments are great for one time, add and forget kind of usage. Beyond that You must manage fragments using java code.

Simply stick to some rules when adding, replacing fragments:

```
Int frameId = // id of host view
Fragment manager = // fragment manager, of Activity or a Fragment
String tag = // unique tag for the fragment
String clazz = // class name of the fragment
Bundle args = // initial data to be supplied to fragment instance

Fragment frg = manager.findFragmentbyTag(tag);

if(frg == null){
  frg = Fragment.instantiate(context,clazz,args);
}

if(!frg.isAdded()){
   manager.beginTransaction().add(frameId, frg, tag).commit();
}
```

If a Fragment has also to show a nested fragment on start, You can use above code in its `onViewCreated()`.

FragmentManager is asynchronous in nature, after `commit()`, it doesn't immediately apply fragment changes. The commit is scheduled to happen sometime in future. `executePendingTransactions()` is available, but should be used with extreme care. It makes all scheduled transactions run immediately, and when they are running, you must not call this again.