# Android Nested Fragments not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to crate a viewpager transition inside a fragment class which itself derived from another fragment class. Whenever I'm trying to create the viewpager its showing the following error.

```
02-09 11:28:34.321: E/AndroidRuntime(8520): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gm.gakkmusic/com.gm.gakkmusic.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
02-09 11:28:34.321: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
02-09 11:28:34.321: E/AndroidRuntime(8520):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
```

After searching for a while in StackOverflow I found that I've to use `getChildFragmentManager()` while nesting a child fragment to its main fragment but I'm kinda confused about the whole process. It would be nice if anyone can figure this problem and give a quick solution.

Sources are given below,

This is where the Fragment1 is created from the MainActivity.class

```
     @Override
        public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            switch (position) {
                case 0:

                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.container, new Fragment1())
                            .commit();
                    break;
    }
}
```

Fragment1.class is the parent Fragment and inside it the child viewpager transition is created,

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    private Fragment contentFragment;
    SliderFragment sliderFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {

            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID) != null) {
                sliderFragment = (SliderFragment) fragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(SliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
                contentFragment = sliderFragment;
            }
        } else {
            sliderFragment = new SliderFragment();
            switchContent(sliderFragment, SliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (contentFragment instanceof SliderFragment) {
            outState.putString("content", SliderFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        while (fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate())
            ;

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);

            if (!(fragment instanceof SliderFragment)) {
                transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
            }
            transaction.commit();
            contentFragment = fragment;
        }
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            super.getActivity().onBackPressed();
        } else if (contentFragment instanceof SliderFragment
                || fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onItemClick: " + position);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "checked items: " + listView.getCheckedItemCount());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                "checked positions: " + listView.getCheckedItemPositions());
    }

}
```

UPDATE: I've already solved the problem by replacing all `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getChildFragmentManager()` but I'm still looking for an efficient way to solve this.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22152267/1777090)

Comment: @FlamePrincessϡ thanks, Already solved the problem but right now looking for an efficient way.