# Android programming

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive entry to executePendingTransactions
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions()
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run()
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Getting this error in crashlytics ?? Any solution for this ??

Comment: search before posting..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150950/recursive-entry-to-executependingtransactions

Comment: Please also post your code so you can get better help.

Comment: how do we supposed to debug you code from exception only, post your context and code

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a code but the problem after a little investigation you simply can't embed one fragment into another you are executing one fragment transaction in another one. not allowed.

New version of Support Library v4 (or Android 4.2, of course) resolves this problem.

getChildFragmentManager() added specifically to tackle the issue. 
But again I cannot see code.